# AJAX: How to read a changing (cronjob-) file live?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'd like to display the output of some changing cronjob-files **live** in an adminpanel.

I know how to read a file via ajax and how to set intervals. But I don't know how to do this live.

Here's some **pseudocode**:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "cronjob.php",
   live: true,
   interval: 4000,
   output: "#outputDiv", // gets updated every 4 seconds
   timeout: 30000
}).done(function() {
   alert("cronjob done.");
});
```

Output:

```
- cronjob start -
Task 1: done (2.3 seconds)
Task 2: done (214.9 seconds)
Task 3: done (19.2 seconds)
- cronjob end -
```

I could use an iframe for the live-effect but I need a callback when the cronjob is done.

Does anyone know how to handle this issue? A jQuery plugin would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with an interval which calls the ajax function

some **pseudocode**:

ajax:

```
function cronlive(intervallid) {
    $.ajax({
            url: "cronjob.php",
            async: false, 
            type: "POST",
            success: function(response) {
                     if(response == 'finished') {
                          window.clearInterval(intervalid);
                     } else {
                          $('#log').append(response);
                     }
            }
    });
}
```

javascript:

```
  $('#showlivecron').click(function() {
       var interval = setInterval(cronlive(interval), 4000); 
  }
```

html:

```
<html>
      <head>
         <!-- include jquery -->
      </head>
      <body>
         <button id="showlivecron">Show Live Cronjobs</button>
         <div id="log"></div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Websockets help you to steam the response on page. You no need to use setInterval & ajax. More like chat application